# How to resolve incoming email error in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a site, https://adsler.co.uk/contact-us/ and its refusing to send emails. I have absolutely no idea why, just getting this error message that says `there was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later`

I'm using a plugin, WordPress Contact Form 7. It's very good and very reliable and used to work perfectly. It can't be the site receiving emails, because it just won't send any. And my outgoing user email is correct and present.

For example, I have this page:https://adsler.co.uk/showcase/ which I just placed a contact form on

The shortcode, if it makes any difference, is: `[contact-form-7 id="9952" title="Showcase"]`

The html is:

```
<label> Your Name (required)
[text* your-name] </label>
<label> Your Email (required)
[email* your-email] </label>

 <label> Subject
[text your-subject] </label>

<label> Your Message
[textarea your-message] </label>

[acceptance acceptance-737] I agree to the <a 
 href="http://adsler.co.uk/showcase-of-the-month-terms/"
>Terms and Conditions</a> [/acceptance]

 [submit class:button "Send"]
```

But I have 3 or 4 contact forms, all cf7, and none of them work....

Comment: We don't know how your contact form works so of course you might get downvotes for not providing enough information/context. Please add more details and people will help, otherwise you're basically asking us to guess what's going on and that's not what SO is for. P.S.: I haven't downvoted you *yet* to give you an opportunity at better explaining the situation to us.

Comment: How about edited question?

Comment: That's better. Please make sure future questions also include as much details as possible. Anyways, have you tried any of these suggestions yet? -> [Contact Form 7 - If You Have Email Problems](https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/#Contact_Form_7_Email_Issues).

Comment: Thanks for that. The only issues I've managed to identify are Recaptcha issues or hosting issues. But how could Recaptcha on one form, stop other forms from working correctly...?

Comment: The site itself is able to send emails. Just checked so...

Comment: Plugin conflict, I don't think so...

Comment: @Stacksof99 fastest way to rule out a plugin conflict is to just deactivate everything except CF7, and try sending the form again. ReCaptcha uses JS i believe, so it's possible that would cause issues sending the form too. My guess would be hosting, has anything changed since it was working?

Comment: Nothing really cept maybe Recaptcha-but I need my Recaptcha... :-(

Comment: @David Alsbright I deleted this `[anr_nocaptcha g-recaptcha-response]` from the only Contact form using Recaptcha and it still doesn't work. Not a hosting issue, apparently, changed default email to another host, still nothing...

Comment: It'll be your _web_ hosting that needs to be checked, not your email hosting. Your web hosting is the entity that sends the mail

Comment: Yeah. I told them that but apparently its not them. And they just said check email hosting...

Comment: @cabrerehector yeah, tried disabling all plugins, defiantly not a site or email hosting issue, disabled Recaptcha... nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Solved, apparently.

It seems that Cf7 has recaptcha `integration.`

Remove the API keys from there and all done. You can still retain the Cf7 Recaptcha 2 with a plugin which has separate API integration. Cf7 says that it doesn't work with Recaptcha 2, which doesn't seem entirely correct. It seems to work with Recaptcha 2 but only with a separate plugin, as far as I can see. If you want Cf7 integration though l, it seems Recaptcha 3 `background validity analytics` is the only way.